# FusionCharts example with template

Tags: vue.js, fusioncharts

Is there anyone knowing how to use the [Vue FusionCharts](https://github.com/fusioncharts/vue-fusioncharts) with the "template"?

I created a test VueJs Component, named `FChart`:

```
<template>
  <fusioncharts
    :type="type"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    :dataFormat="dataFormat"
    :dataSource="dataSource"
  ></fusioncharts>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import VueFusionCharts from "vue-fusioncharts";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import TimeSeries from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.timeseries";

// register VueFusionCharts component
Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, TimeSeries);

var jsonify = res => res.json();
var dataFetch = fetch("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/data/line-chart-with-time-axis-data.json").then(jsonify);
var schemaFetch = fetch("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/schema/line-chart-with-time-axis-schema.json").then(jsonify);

export default {
  name: "FChart",
  data() {
    return {
      width: "100%",
      height: "400",
      type: "timeseries",
      dataFormat: "json",
      dataSource: {
        chart: {},
        caption: {
          text: "Sales Analysis"
        },
        subcaption: {
          text: "Grocery"
        },
        yaxis: [
          {
            plot: {
              value: "Grocery Sales Value"
            },
            format: {
              prefix: "$"
            },
            title: "Sale Value"
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    Promise.all([dataFetch, schemaFetch]).then(res => {
      const data = res[0];
      const schema = res[1];
      const fusionTable = new FusionCharts.DataStore().createDataTable(
        data,
        schema
      );
      this.dataSource.data = fusionTable;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

And my App.vue does the following:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <FChart />
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import FChart from "./components/FChart";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { FChart }
};
</script>
```

but this does not work. I have in the console an error message saying:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLogicalSpace' of undefined
>     at e.i.manageSpace (fusioncharts.timeseries.js?79dd:1)
>     at e.t.updateVisual (fusioncharts.js?8f68:13)
>     at Object.e.__drawJob [as job] (fusioncharts.js?8f68:13)
>     at b (fusioncharts.js?8f68:13)
> ```

I

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of researches and tries, here is the version not really different from the initial one, however:

```
<template>
  <fusioncharts
    :type="type"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    :dataFormat="dataFormat"
    :dataSource="dataSource"
  ></fusioncharts>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import VueFusionCharts from "vue-fusioncharts";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import TimeSeries from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.timeseries";

Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, TimeSeries);

const jsonify = res => res.json();
const dataFetch = fetch(
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/data/line-chart-with-time-axis-data.json"
).then(jsonify);
const schemaFetch = fetch(
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/schema/line-chart-with-time-axis-schema.json"
).then(jsonify);

export default {
  name: "FChart",
  data() {
    return {
      type: "timeseries",
      width: "100%",
      height: "500",
      dataFormat: "json",
      dataSource: {
        data: null,
        caption: {
          text: "Sales Analysis"
        },
        subcaption: {
          text: "Grocery"
        },
        yAxis: [
          {
            plot: {
              value: "Grocery Sales Value",
              type: "line"
            },
            format: {
              prefix: "$"
            },
            title: "Sale Value"
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }, 
  mounted: function() {
    // In this Promise we will create our DataStore and using that we will create a custom DataTable which takes two
    // parameters, one is data another is schema.
    Promise.all([dataFetch, schemaFetch]).then(res => {
      const data = res[0];
      const schema = res[1];
      // First we are creating a DataStore
      const fusionDataStore = new FusionCharts.DataStore();
      // After that we are creating a DataTable by passing our data and schema as arguments
      const fusionTable = fusionDataStore.createDataTable(data, schema);
      // After that we simply mutated our timeseries datasource by attaching the above
      // DataTable into its data property.
      this.dataSource.data = fusionTable;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i found my answer in your problem. I was not able to print any chart. But i just needed to add my data directly to this.dataSource.data.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the sample code -

```
// STEP 1: to include the dependencies
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueFusionCharts from 'vue-fusioncharts';
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import Column2D from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';

Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, Column2D, FusionTheme);

// STEP 2: Prepare the data
const chartData = [
    {
      label: "Venezuela",
      value: "290"
    },
    {
      label: "Saudi",
      value: "260"
    },
    {
      label: "Canada",
      value: "180"
    },
    {
      label: "Iran",
      value: "140"
    },
    {
      label: "Russia",
      value: "115"
    },
    {
      label: "UAE",
      value: "100"
    },
    {
      label: "US",
      value: "30"
    },
    {
      label: "China",
      value: "30"
    }
  ];

// STEP 3: Configure your chart
const dataSource = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
    subcaption: "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
    xaxisname: "Country",
    yaxisname: "Reserves (MMbbl)",
    numbersuffix: "K",
    theme: "fusion"
  },
  data: chartData
  };

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      "type": "column2d",
      "renderAt": "chart-container",
      "width": "550",
      "height": "350",
      "dataFormat": "json",
      dataSource
    }
  }
}
</script>

//STEP 4: Render the chart
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="chart-container">
      <fusioncharts
      :type="type"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
      :dataformat="dataFormat"
      :dataSource="dataSource"
      >
      </fusioncharts>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

To know more about this feature - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/vue/your-first-chart-using-vuejs

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/vue/configure-your-chart-using-vuejs